# Running Artisan Serve Doesnt work

Tags: php, macos, laravel, configuration

I am running on Laravel 5.3.
Whenever I try to `php artisan serve` and type `localhost:8000`, It returns phpinfo. Now additional confusion has it when I cancel the `serve` then refresh it still shows the phpinfo

[image: phpinfo]

Is there any solution to this as to what have I messed up(I am using mac air)
Any help would be great!

Comment: what is your console is showing ?

Comment: Hi, @AbdouTahiri, it shows nothing. 
Is it in my inner configs? also i've tried without serve it still shows.

Comment: how checked the port 8000 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try another command to change the port of the localhost :

```
php -S localhost:1988 -t public
```

Comment: not an existing directory, what i've found though is that my machine favors the nginx over my artisan command. when I killed the server(nginx) it all stopped even though I've runned the `serve` command.

Comment: You're using OS right ? if Yes then do `sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: Thanks It worked! by the way. is laravel using apache as its main server?

Comment: Laravel recommends  using `Homstead` which uses `Nginx` not `Apache`

Answer (score 0):

First check your :8000 port may be its busy .

```
netstat -anp tcp | grep 8000
```

You can kill it or try to load it using another port .

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

Comment: `tcp4       0      0  *.8000                 *.*                    LISTEN`

that is the result

Comment: do you have a running vbox on that port ?

Comment: I've checked my local machine. It seems like my nginx server is the priority of it all. when I killed the server the phpinfo didnt work. now when I ran `serve` again, it still wont work.

Comment: is MAMP considered a vbox?

Comment: no, but you might need to check why its not working on :8000, however have you tried to serve on another port ?  ```php artisan serve --port=8080 ```

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem. Any use of `php artisan` returned `phpinfo()`. The reason was the incorrect code `dd(phpinfo())` in my `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::any('/any', dd(phpinfo()));
```